# How can I fix this syntax error involving the FROM clause?

Tags: mysql

I am working on a simple problem set, and I cannot seem to find the issue that is generating this same error: "Syntax Error in FROM Clause".

The question involves the use of various databases in this instant to find "Which employee has sold the most product?"

Here is my code

```
SELECT (Employees.FirstName + Employees.LastName) as Employee, SUM(Orders.Quantity)
FROM Employees, Orders
JOIN Employees ON Orders.EmployeeID=Employees.EmployeeID
JOIN OrderDetails ON Orders.OrderID=OrderDetails.OrderID
GROUP BY Employee
ORDER BY max(SUM(Quantity)) DESC;
```

If I am misinterpreting the use of some syntax, please let me know. I am still learning.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're using ANSI JOIN you don't list all the tables in the `FROM` clause. Just list the first table, and the other tables are in `JOIN`.

You also can't nest aggregate functions as `MAX(SUM(Quantity))`. If you want to find the employee who sold the most, order by quantity, and use `TOP 1` to get the first row.

There's no need to join with `OrderDetails`, since you're not using anything from that table.

The query should be:

```
SELECT TOP 1 (Employees.FirstName + Employees.LastName) as Employee, SUM(Orders.Quantity) AS Quantity
FROM Employees
JOIN Orders ON Orders.EmployeeID=Employees.EmployeeID
GROUP BY Employee
ORDER BY Quantity DESC;
```

Note that if there's a tie for the most sold, this will just show one of them. Getting all of them is more complex, because you need a second query to get that maximum. See [sql HAVING max(count()) return zero rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28524825/sql-having-maxcount-return-zero-rows)

Comment: Apologies, I accidentally omitted ON. The code that read as follows still generates an "Syntax Error in the FROM clause"  SELECT (Employees.FirstName + Employees.LastName) as Employee, SUM(Orders.Quantity)
FROM Employees
JOIN Orders ON Orders.EmployeeID=Employees.EmployeeID
JOIN OrderDetails ON Orders.OrderID=OrderDetails.OrderID
GROUP BY Employee
ORDER BY Quantity DESC

Comment: Are you sure you're using MySQL? That looks like a SQL-Server error message, not MySQL.

Comment: And MySQL uses `CONCAT()` to concatenate strings, not `+`.

Comment: w3schools has both MySQL and SQL-Server tutorials.